# Display a part of the page by the hash in the url using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well, this project came to my mind cause of this problem:
When I hit the register button, the PHP script is gonna process it and it displays error but the page is gonna be at the login form.

The interface:
[image: Login Page][image: Register Page]

The idea now:
If the url has some parameter in it, process it into the *jQuery*, and display the requested page from the url. 
 
Example: someurl.com/#login - then display the Login Page 
someurl.com/#register - then display the Register Page

Tried solution (jQuery):

```
$(function() {
// get the `hash` from the url
var url = window.location.hash;
// display the page
$(url).show();
}
```

---

My codes right now:

The *script*:

```
$(function() {
    var url = window.location.hash;
    $(url).show();

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).prop('title', 'Login | Prospekt');
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).prop('title', 'Register | Prospekt');
    });

});
```

The forms:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="panel panel-login">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" class="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <form id="login-form" action="http://phpoll.com/login/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: block;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                                        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                        <label for="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                <div class="text-center">
                                                    <a href="http://phpoll.com/recover" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <form id="register-form" action="http://phpoll.com/register/process" method="post" role="form" style="display: none;">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register Now">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <!--
                    <hr>
                        <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible">
                          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                          Username is required! <br>
                          Password is required!
                        </div>
                    -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the demo, here is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t2773hwf/)

Comment: y not u try simply bootstrap tabs

Comment: Well, this is the one that i'm working with, and i'm a pretty *beginner* at Bootstrap and jQuery, but as far as I know that this project is also a Bootstrap Tabs.

Comment: Add data-toggle="tab" to each tab, and add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them in a .tab-content class. ,for beginners refer w3schools

Comment: Thanks for that tip :) I already added a unique ID for both of them, and I followed that tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get your hash from the url, call the click() event corresponding to that hash after declaring the click handlers.

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).prop('title', 'Login | Prospekt');
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).prop('title', 'Register | Prospekt');
    });

    var url = window.location.hash;
    $(url + '-form-link').click();
});
```

Comment: Well, the `url` returns the hash from the url with a # already, is the `$('#'` needed?

Comment: Well, for no reasons. It doesn't work :( I've tried putting a hash in the url (#register) and it should click or trigger an event, but nothing happened.

Comment: do a console.log(url) and let us know

Comment: It shows the current hash in the url, like #register or #login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129675/discussion-between-astronomicalxoom-and-phobia82).